# How to access my subcollection the correct way?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am struggling to find the right solution in flutter to get the values of my user's sub-collection in Cloud Firestore!

This is my user holding the collection "affiliations"
[image: user with sub-collection]

These are the contents of the sub-collection "affiliations". In this case there are two references to organizations.
[image: affiliations collection]

At runtime I would like to identify if a specific user is connected to an organization (organization key appears in referenced document).

So I have the user id and the organization id. How would you solve this?

Cheers!

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you have tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  If you are new to Firestore and want to learn how to perform queries, start with the documentation.  https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly, the path would be:

```
firestore.collection('users')
.doc(user_id)
.collection('affiliations')
.doc(organization_id)
.get().then((snapshot){
    //do something with your snapshot
    });
```

Above is the recommended way but I see you would need to rename your documents in organization to be the organization id.

What you could do but is unnecessary:

```
firestore.collection('users').
    .doc(user_id)
    .collection('affiliations')
    .where('organization', isEqualTo: 'organization/idstring')
    .get((querySnapshot){
    //do somthing here
});
```

Comment: It's as if you were reading my mind JayJay: your (excellent) answer assumes that OP implements my suggestion of changing their document IDs. :)

Comment: oh now I realize it. Yes you are right. I assumed he was doing it, because otherwise he would need to query the 'affiliation' collection and look for a document where the organization key is equal to the certain id he wants.

Comment: Thanks a lot so far, guys! Right, a user may have more than one organization assigned to. Later I would like to store other assets under the affiliations sub-collection as well. That's why I labeled the item "orgsanization" and gave it the reference as the value. Would you do it completely different?

Answer (score 1):

If a specific user can only be affiliated with a specific organization once, I recommend using the organization ID as the document ID for that affiliation too. That way you don't have to query, but can directly check if a document with that ID exists.

While it may not make a big performance difference, it will keep your data more readable **and** allow you to check whether the user is affiliated with an organization in your security rules - something that isn't possible in your current structure.